# Entity Framework 5 Generates SQL Referencing NotMapped Property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I just set about updating a project from Entity Framework 4.3.1 and .NET 4 to Entity Framework 5.0 and .NET 4.5.  I updated the .NET version first, and ensured that I'm referencing EF 5.0.0.0 rather than the .NET 4 compatible 4.4.0.0.

I have a class structure like

```
public class MyBase
{
    [NotMapped]
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyDefinition : MyBase
{
    // Some other properties
}
```

When I attempt to load some MyDefinition instances

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
{
    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    var defs = from def in ctx.MyDefinitions.AsNoTracking() select def;

    foreach (MyDefinition def in defs) // <-- Exception here
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I get a SqlException

> Invalid column name 'MyProperty'.

It is as if *NotMapped* is respected for purposes of determining whether the existing schema is valid, but the SELECT generated by EF 5 expects there to be a *MyProperty* column.

The base class and derived class are defined in different assemblies.  Both assemblies were carefully checked to ensure they reference EF 5.0.0.0 and target .NET 4.5.

Intellisense claims that *NotMapped* is *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped*

How can I prevent EF 5 from selecting that non-existent column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh!

I also updated to VS 2012 today.  Something unrelated broke with a post-build event, which caused an earlier version of the assembly containing the base class to be available to the derived class.  Fixing the post build event resolved the issue.

Comment: Hey Eric, just wanted to confirm that this means you are no longer seeing any issues with NotMapped?

Comment: @RowanMiller: That is correct.  Due to the build problem, my code was referencing an old version of my DLL that still referenced NotMapped in the wrong name space.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
```